# Some tabular problems

Tags: tables

Would someone mind helping me out with some tabular problems that I am having ? Basically, my table is going off the page (I am not that good at defining tables with text) and if anyone has any other good ideas to make this table more clean, I would greatly appreciate it. Here is the code I am working with:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{ amssymb }
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
        \toprule
        Topics & General $(n \times n)$ matrix & Hermitian & Real Symmetric \\
        \midrule
        Eigenvalues & Always have $n$ eigenvalues, \\

        & some may be repeated or c.c & All real eigenvalues & Real symmetric  \\[.5\normalbaselineskip]
        Eigenvectors & \\ \tabitem eigenvectors are l.i \\ for distinct eigenvalues \\
                       \tabitem If there are $n$ distinct \\ eigenvalues, then the eigenvectors forms \\ a basis for $C^n$ \\ & Orthogonal for distinct eigenvalues \\ &  They always form an orthonormal matrix \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And here is a picture of the problem I am having:[image]

I am not that familiar with adding longer text in tables as I have mainly been using it for displaying numbers but if someone could give some advice, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry it was taken from a subsection of my actual document so I copied and pasted most of the packages ! I did edit it and remove a majority of it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following might be what you are looking for, but i am not sure.

[image: putsandcallsTabular]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xl}
    \toprule
    Topics & General $(n \times n)$ matrix & Hermitian & Real Symmetric \\
    \midrule
    Eigenvalues  & Always have $n$ eigenvalues, some may be repeated or c.c    & All real eigenvalues & Real symmetric  \\
    Eigenvectors & \tabitem eigenvectors are l.i for distinct eigenvalues \par
    \tabitem If there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues, then the eigenvectors forms a basis for $C^n$             & Orthogonal for distinct eigenvalues They always form an orthonormal matrix \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that is perfect, thank you ! So the main difference is that you typed `\par` which allowed it to be defined as a paragraph ? Also, may I quickly ask what you defined with `{\linewidth}{l>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}Xl}` so that I can generalize your procedure ?

Comment: @PutsandCalls The tabular(x) is defined to have a total width of `\linewidth`, which is pobably the same as `\textwidth` in your case. The two columns in the middle are defined to be of type `X`, meaning an algorithm calculates the best width for the columns. Additionally, those columns are typeset ragged on the right (not justified), which is common for narrow columns. Within a paragraph column (X), `\par` is used to get to the next paragraph (*i.e.* a new line).